# Blazor render-mode="Server" for displaying the component not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I am trying to display a blazor component from a razor page by setting `render-mode="Server"` but it is not displaying the component. That is the below code is not working.

```
<component type="typeof(BlazorRC.Pages.SelectCity)" render-mode="Server" />
```

However when I change it to `render-mode="ServerPrerendered"` then the component displays. That is the below code works.

```
<component type="typeof(BlazorRC.Pages.SelectCity)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Why is this happening?? What should I do to make `render-mode="Server"` to work??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `blazor.server.js` script link after calling the component in the Razor Page.

```
<component type="typeof(BlazorRC.Pages.SelectCity)" render-mode="Server" />

<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Note that `render-mode="ServerPrerendered"` does not need the `blazor.server.js`.