# Razor Component does not render in Asp.net core MVC 6 on host

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly, razor-components

Razor Component does not render for security layer of Cloudflare

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using minify setting in cloudflare cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<SliderComponent>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

Please check this link to see the difference: [RenderMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.rendermode?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

If you must use `RenderMode.Server`, you can try the way of referencing `blazor.server.js`: [Blazor render-mode="Server" for displaying the component not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65289013/18789859).